# "Respect de" dans le sens radiologique

Tags: santé-et-médecine

J'ai les résultats d'un examen IRM, où se trouvent quelques phrases qui commencent avec « Respect de » :

> Sur le plan tendineux et musculaires:
>
> Respect de l'insertion proximale du sartorius ainsi que du muscle
> tenseur du fascia lata.
> Respect du biceps fémoral ainsi que du tractus ilio-tibial.
> Respect l'insertion proximale des ischio-jambiers.
> Respect de l'insertion du droit fémoral ainsi que son tendon indirect.

Qu'est ce que ça veut dire, RESPECT DE dans ce sens ? Est-ce bon ou mauvais ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***Respect*** signifie ici que le traumatisme subi par la personne examinée a **épargné** (donc **respecté**) les muscles et tendons cités.

Dans le cas contraire, on aurait parlé d'élongation, de déchirure ou de rupture.

> TLFi [Respecter](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/respecter)
> **B.-**, **2.** [Avec un complément d'objet concret] Ne pas détruire ou modifier quelque chose. Synon. *épargner*, *ménager*. *Le port a été partiellement respecté par la guerre, et sa puissance de manutention et de stockage était établie dès la fin de 1947* (Nav. intér. Fr., 1952, p. 63).

Answer (score 1):

Je pense que cela veut dire que l'insertion... est normale.

Comment: J'ai trouvé d'autres exemples d'usage de cette phrase sur l'Internet, dans les examens radiologiques, mais pas d'explication, ni assez de contexte pour deviner si c'est normale ou pas. Merci pour votre réponse, et si quelqu'un aurait une définition un peu plus formelles, j'apprécierais !